# How to put the settings functionality for GCM Push Notification on/off inside the app in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I integrated GCM push notification for my iOS app. I did some research about turn off/on apple push notification inside the app. There is a way using 'unregisterForRemoteNotifications'. But unfortunately it's not working on iOS 10. Is there any way for turn off/on GCM push notification inside the app?

Answer (score 0):

This statement in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1623093-unregisterforremotenotifications?language=objc) regarding `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` might help you:

> You should call this method in rare circumstances only, such as when a new version of the app removes support for all types of remote notifications. Users can temporarily prevent apps from receiving remote notifications through the Notifications section of the Settings app. Apps unregistered through this method can always re-register.

Additional insights can also be found in [this forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63038). As mentioned, best solution  is mark app capability `background fetch`. That will make `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` be called after call `registerForRemoteNotifications`.

In addition to that, you may want to also check suggested solutions in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683785/how-to-put-the-settings-functionality-for-gcm-push-notification-on-off-inside-th) .